# How can I avoid replacement has length zero error

Tags: r, frequency, zero

I am trying to generate the term frequency matrix of a document and subsequently look up the frequency of a certain word in a given query in that matrix. In the end I want to sum the frequencies found of the words in the query. 
However, I am coping with the error message: Error in feature[i] <- x : replacement has length zero

I do not have a lot of coding experience in general, and this is my first time working with R, thus I am having difficulties solving this error. I presume it has something to do with a null-value. I already tried to avoid the nested for-loop with an apply function because I thought that might help (not sure though), but I could not quite get the hang of how to convert the for-loop into an apply function.

```
termfreqname <- function(queries,docs){
  n <- length(queries)
  feature <- vector(length=n)
  for(i in 1:n){
    query <- queries[i]
    documentcorpus <- c(docs[i])

    tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(tm_corpus) #creates the term frequency matrix per document
    m <- sapply(strsplit(query, " "), length) #length of the query in words
    totalfreq <- list(0) #initialize list
    freq_counter <- rowSums(as.matrix(tdm)) #counts the occurrence of a given word in the tdm matrix

    for(j in 1:m){
      freq <- freq_counter[word(query,j)] #finds frequency of each word in the given query, in the term frequency matrix
      totalfreq[[j]] <- freq #adds this frequency to position j in the list
    }
    x <- reduce(totalfreq,'+') #sums all the numbers in the list
    feature[i] <- x #adds this number to feature list
  feature    
  }
}
```

Comment: Depending on your use, you can either choose `if (length(x)) feature[i] <- x` or if `NA` is meaningful/useful to you, then `feature[i] <- if (length(x)) x else NA`. For me, since `vector(length=n)` defaults to a vector of `FALSE`, I find it better to distinguish between *"confirmed to be false"* (a literal `FALSE`) and *"uncertain"* (`NA`). (The class of `feature` might change once you start making assignments, in which case it would be the distinction between *"confirmed to be a count of zero"* and *"uncertain"*.)

Comment: `reduce(totalfreq,'+')` is flawed. It should be `\`+\`` instead of `'+'`. Why don't you use `sum`?

Comment: @MartinGal, I think it should be `\`+\`` instead of your suggested `\`x\``. I second the lean towards `sum`. Realize, though, that it looks like `totalfreq` *might* be a `list`, in which case `sum` fails, and `reduce(totalfreq, \`+\`)` works. As does `sum(unlist(totalfreq))` (which is likely much faster with larger data).

Comment: @r2evans *facepalm* Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your needs, but bottom line you need to add some `if` statement. How you use it depends on whether you want the default value of the vector to persist. In your code, while `feature` starts as a logical vector, it is likely coerced to `integer` or `numeric` once you overwrite its first value with a number. In that case, the default value in all positions of the vector will be `0` (or `0L`, if integer). That's going to influence your decision on how to use the `if` statement.

```r
if (length(x)) feature[i] <- x
```

This will only attempt to overwrite the `i`th value of `feature` if the `x` objects has length (that's equivalent to `if (length(x) > 0)`). In this case, since the default value in the vector will be zero, this means when you are done that you will not be able to distinguish between an element known to be `0` and an element that failed to find anything.

The alternative (and my preference/recommendation):

```r
feature[i] <- if (length(x)) x else NA
```

In this case, when you are done, you can clearly distinguish between known-zero (`0`) and uncertain/unknown values (`NA`). When doing math operations on that vector, you might want/need `na.rm=TRUE` ... but it all depends on your use.

BTW, as MartinGal noted, your use of `reduce(totalfreq, '+')` is a little flawed: `'x'` may not be (is not?) recognized as a known function. The first fix to this is to use backticks around the function, so

```r
totalfreq <- 5:7
reduce(totalfreq, '+')
# NULL
reduce(totalfreq, `+`)
# [1] 18
sum(totalfreq)
# [1] 18
```

There the last is the much-more-preferred method. Why? With a vector of length 4, for instance, it takes the first two and adds them, then takes that result and adds it to the third, then takes that result and adds to the fourth. Three operations. When you have 100 elements, it will make 99 individual additions. `sum` does it once, and this does have an effect on performance (asymptotically).

However, if `totalfreq` is instead a `list`, then this changes slightly:

```r
totalfreq <- as.list(5:7)
reduce(totalfreq, `+`)
# [1] 18
sum(totalfreq)
# Error in sum(totalfreq) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument
# x
sum(unlist(totalfreq))
# [1] 18
```

The `reduce` code still works, and the `sum` by itself fails, but we can `unlist` the list first, effectively creating a vector, and then call `sum` on that. Much much faster asymptotically. And perhaps clearer, more declarative.

(I'm assuming `purrr::reduce`, btw ...)